# I have imported a Breadcrumb module from Primeng and tryting to use as example. But it is giving error in my template

Tags: angular, primeng, menuitem, breadcrumbs

I am trying to use Breadcrumb menu from primeng in my angular project. I have imported it in `app.module.ts` file .But still its giving error in my template. Is there any thing I have to do?

**It is giving below error:**

```
p-breadcrumb' is not a known element:

1. If 'p-breadcrumb' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'p-breadcrumb' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. Error occurs in the template of component BreadcrumbComponent and I am not able to solve this.
```

I have import import {BreadcrumbModule} from `primeng/breadcrumb`;
and still its not working as well as import {BreadcrumbModule} from `primeng/breadcrumb`;. Imported to `.ts` file.

I want to solve solve this error

**Image 1**

[image]

**Image 2**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your screenshots i guess you declared the breadcrumb component in your own BreadcrumbModule. but you are importing the primeNg BreadcrumbModule in the AppModule.

you should move or copy the primeNg import to your own BreadcrumbModule (the module where your BreadcrumbComponent is declared)